# iptables to accept HTTP traffic to one domain only

Tags: iptables

the request is as follows:

1. Redirect all requests to the internet "http" to a local server 192.168.2.100/24.
2. The requests to the www.example.com domain accept them.

This is a wifi service in the community so that visitors can only access www.example.com and if another web page is detected, then redirect to the local server.

I'm trying this:

It works, but does not allow the requirement 2.

## Accepts request to domain www.example.com (This does not work)

iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 98 -p tcp -d www.example.com --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

## Redirect all requests to the internet to the local server (This works)

```
iptables -N inter4 -t mangle
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j inter4
iptables -t mangle -A inter4 -j MARK --set-mark 99
iptables -t mangle -A inter4 -j LOG --
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 99 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT \
         --to-destination 192.168.2.100:8080
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks.

Comment: As you're working at HTTP(S) layer, what you want to do is easier using a proxy.

Comment: @Fredi But you can't proxy Facebook. It's on https.

Comment: @MichaelHampton proxies can handle https, but all they will see is the desired hostname.

Comment: @JasonMartin You don't seem to have understood the question. He is running a public wireless access point. You can't _intercept_ https without SSL bump, and you can't do that without configuring a certificate on the clients, which you can't do for John Q. Public in advance.

Comment: Oh, yes you can't transparently proxy HTTPS without that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, you can tcp ptoxy it using the CONNECT method. Obviously you won't be able to see what passes through, but at least you can set your ACL rules based on the domain name rather that single IP's. At least to me this seems more "right"

Comment: @Fredi You also don't seem to have understood the question.